# Can I trigger the mobile menu earlier on Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I read somewhere that it can be done with Elementor ([reference](https://docs.phlox.pro/article/178-trigger-burger-menu-manually)), but can it be done any other way?
Now it's set on 600px, but I want it triggered at 1200px. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the CSS code to hide and show the menu on a specific device size.

You can use the following CSS code.

```
@media(max-width:1200px)
{
.YourDesktopMenu{
display:none !important;
}
.YourMobileMenu{
display:block !important;
}
}
```

This CSS code helps to hide the desktop menu and show the mobile menu for the lower screen then 1200px.